# Java Map: как получить в методе entrySet значения из базы?

Tags: java, redis, java-hashmap

Всем привет.

Делаю обёртку над базой данных (redis) через интерфейс Map. Данные по факту хранятся в базе, но я получаю их через стандартные методы (put, get и т.д.), которые реализую сам.

Возник вопрос по методу entrySet(). Как мне его реализовать в рамках моей задачи?
Проблема в том, что сейчас не совсем понимаю, как формируются и возвращаются значения. Плюс, как я понял, объект Set, который возвращает entrySet(), может ещё влиять на саму Map (удалять, проверять и т.д. значения).

Как мне лучше реализовать итератор и получение следующего элемента, если все значения в базе?

Что я более-менее (но не факт, что верно) понимаю сейчас:

1. Мне нужна собственная реализация AbstractSet, чтобы вернуть значение в entrySet. Плюс, скорее всего может понадобится собственная реализация Map.Entry
2. Дальше интереснее. Исходник из HashMap класса

```
    public Set<Map.Entry<K,V>> entrySet() {
        Set<Map.Entry<K,V>> es;
        return (es = entrySet) == null ? (entrySet = new EntrySet()) : es;
    }
```

Класс EntrySet() явно ничего не возвращает. Зато реализует Iterator и Spliterator. Spliterator принимает HashMap.this в качестве параметра, т.е. саму HashMap

3. Есть предположение, что Spliterator делает перебор по HashMap, в результате чего формируется корректный Set элементов, который и возвращает EntrySet()

Смотрел исходники тут 
http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/HashMap.java

Смотрел похожий вопрос тут (с достаточно развёрнутым ответом)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30702183/how-entryset-works-internally-in-hashmap

Не жду решения, полезными будут даже объяснения на примере Hashmap. Может быть я упускаю какую-то важную особенность реализации интерфейса Map.
Может там инстанс подключения передавать. А может там вообще всё проще можно сделать, а я просто усложняю.

**UPD1**
Возможно, стоит подумать в сторону SCAN функции в Redis и получать значения из базы итеративно, как это происходит в HashMap. Пока не уверен, на сколько адекватно это будет в рамках оптимизации, но нужно попробовать сделать тестовый концепт для проверки теории.

Comment: Если плясать от печки, то первичным образом/маппингом (неважно как называть) данных в БД к данным в Java является `ResultSet`, предположу, что ваш `Map` должен быть оберткой над `ResultSet` - иначе не взлетит. Вернее возможна будет только тривиальная реализация - прочитать все данные и засунуть их в `Map/HashMap`, но очевидно это не то чего вы хотите. Вы же хотите, чтобы курсор к данным оставался живым внутри вашего `Map`?

Comment: @Barmaley спасибо за ответ. Извиняюсь, что долго не отвечал.

Хорошо, я посмотрю по поводу `ResultSet`. Мне для начала бы разобраться хотя бы с тривиальной реализацией, но в идеале - да. Хотелось бы, чтобы это было похоже на HashMap реализацию.
На сколько я понял, все значения для HashMap лежат в массиве, к которому мы обращаемся при вызове `entrySet` и подобных функций. В результате этого мы и удаление динамическое можем делать. 
Но это если очень сильно упрощать.